# jQuery method not permanent?

Tags: jquery, methods

I'm running some jQuery/JavaScript events/methods and they work only for a moment after which the whole document regains it's former content. How come?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //jquery
        $("#f").submit(function(){
            $("h3").toggle();
            //alert("hello");
        });
        $("button").click(function(){
            alert("ZZZZZ");
        });
      });
    </script>
    <title>Catalog Nova Grup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h3 style="color:#00F">Catalog Nova Grup</h3>
    </center>
    <form id="f">
       <select id="s1">
         <option>---</option>
         <option>ZZZ</option>
       </select>
       <select id="s2"></select>
       <select id="s3"></select>
       <input type="submit" id="sb" />
     </form>
     <button>ZZZ</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post some html and js code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to either `return false` from your event handler or use `e.preventDefault()` where `e` is the event object passed to your event handler.

For example, in the `submit` handler attached to a `<form>` element you should do either:

```
$("#f").submit(function() {
    //do your stuff

    return false //stop browser following link
});
```

or:

```
$("#f").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop browser following link

    //do your stuff
});
```

**EDIT:**
What's happening is the browser is submitting the form, which by default results in the page reloading

Answer (score 2):

Because the form is being submitted, stop it with `return false;`. Alternatively add a parameter to the submit anonymous function and call `.preventDefault()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //jquery                      
    $("#f").submit(function () {
        $("h3").toggle();
        //alert("hello");
        return false;
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
        alert("ZZZZZ");
    });
});
```